# how to use javascript value in java code in webview?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, webview

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

        webView.evaluateJavascript("alert('hi'); var elem = 
        document.querySelector('.price__container__discount__sales_price').firstChild.innerHTML;" 
        ,null);

        btn.setText(elem);
}
```

i want use elem variable that declare in js into java code in setText methode

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a value from your javascript code loaded into your webview, I would expose a method with the @JavascriptInterface annotation that would gather that value from your javascript.

An example of how to do that is below:

***NATIVE***

```
//Make sure to enable these settings
  webviewSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  addJavascriptInterface(YOUR_INTERFACE_CLASS, YOUR_INTERFACE_NAME);

 @JavascriptInterface
    public void getSalesPrice(String value) {
        //Here you will get the value from your javascript
    }
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
function sendDataToNative(data) {
        YOUR_INTERFACE_NAME.getSalesPrice(data);
    }
```